# Spark write operation HDFS using temporal path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to write to a csv file from this Scala code. I'm using HDFS as a temp directory, then just writer.write to create a new file in an existing subfolder. I get the following error message:

```
val inputFile = "s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/rawdata.csv" //  INPUT path 
val outputFile = "s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv" //  OUTPUT path 
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
val fileSystem = getFileSystem(inputFile)
val inputData = readCSVFile(fileSystem, inputFile, skipHeader = true).toSeq

val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFile))
writer.write("Sales,cust,Number,Date,Credit,SKU\n")
filtinp.foreach(x => {
  val (com1, avg1) = com1Average(filtermp, x)
  val (com2, avg2) = com2Average(filtermp, x)
  writer.write(s"${x.Date},${x.cust},${x.Number},${x.Credit}\n")
})
writer.close()

def getFileSystem(path: String): FileSystem = {
val hconf = new Configuration() // initialize new hadoop configuration
new Path(path).getFileSystem(hconf) // get new filesystem to handle data
```

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv (No such file or directory)**

same happens if I choose new file or exiting one, I've checked the path is correct, just want to create a new file in there.

Problem is in order to write data using file system based source you'll need a temporal directory, this is a part of the commit mechanism used by Spark, i.e data is first written to a temporary directory, and once the tasks are finished, automatically moved the processed file to the final path.

Should I change the path to the temp folder for each Spark application to S3? I think is better to process locally (Local Files HDFS) then upload the processed output file to S3

Also I just see there is no "No Spark configuration set" in the databricks cluster I'm using, this interferes with the issue?

Comment: can you paste your full code as this code looks partial and not able to understand what you you are trying to do?

Comment: just computing to get averages group by customer and SKU

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to read the raw data using spark/scala in the form of the DataFrame then you could perform transformations on your dataframe to build the final dataframe. Once you have the final dataframe then needs to be written as csv file you can just use the below single line of code to save the csv file to s3 bucket path or the hdfs path.

```
df.write.format('csv').option('header','true').mode('overwrite').option('sep',',').save('s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv')
```